# Jquery Drag and Drop Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am wondering if is possible to implement a drag and drop feature as a novel way of searching a table. For example a table displaying weather results, there are 4 icons of sun, snow, rain, wind. When the sun icon is dropped it will only display the sun rows.

I know that when an Item is dropped you can write to html or alert but I am wondering if it is possible to write to a variable which in turn would search the table.

Reference for searching through the table: http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2011/01/03/searching-text-in-a-html-table-using-jquery/

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is, yes. And I have to admit it is a novel way of organizing a list of data in the DOM.

So what you would need is a callback on the droppable method. Something like this:

```
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
drop: function( event, ui ) {
$(--non-dropped selector or attr--).each(function(){
         $(this).hide();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats great mate, I am going to have a bash tonight and will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Glad it worked for u ...great design idea too .. i may rip it off on a future project :P